# Fail to download/upload a ppt file

Tags: php, apache, download, zip, powerpoint

I have a web site that allows users to download different kinds of code projects.

These projects are zipped and then sent to the client machine on demand.
In case one of this projects contain a "ppt" (power point) file, and the user gets the following error:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/dzz82rfc9/]

Comment: Can you tell us, How is this related to PHP?

Comment: Moved the image from the link to be embedded in the post.

Answer (score 0):

How is this relevant to PHP? 
Are you creating the ZIP on the server? Are you setting a PHP header to download the file?

Perhaps try:

```
// The user will receive a ZIP to download
header('Content-type: application/zip');

// File will be called downloaded.zip
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.zip"');

// The actual ZIP file on the server is source.zip
readfile('source.zip');
```

Failing that, try downloading the zip via FTP and unzipping it on your local machine... perhaps it's corrupt.

Comment: title edited , yes the zip is created on the server . any zip that does not contain ppt works fine ...

Comment: So the zip is created with PHP?  Do the ppt files have the same file permissions as the other files? What happens if you rename a text file ``text.ppt`` or conversely if you rename a ppt file to be .pptx or .txt - does the error still occur?  
Have you tried adding a ``sleep(5);`` command after the zip is created, but before it is downloaded, to give the server time to generate the zip?

Comment: yes it's created with php , yes , if I change a txt file to ppt it works fine and if i change a ppt file to txt the same problem occurs . tried adding sleep, nothing changed